# Use list items as values in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list in such format:

```
com = ['eto', 'eti', 'etn', 'ets', 'eot', 'eoi', 'eon', 'eos', 'eit', 'eio', 'ein']
```

Then in the program I need perform 3 different calculations with each character in each cell.

```
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[e]) for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[t]) for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[o]) for w in newC]
```

And next time it does

```
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[e]) for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[t]) for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], com[i]) for w in newC]
```

and so on, in a loop, so I don't hardcode those characters, they should be takes from the list.

Essentially I want those three list comprehensions to cycle through each combination for example first time they use 'e', 't' and 'o' respectively, then 'e', 't', and 'i' respectively and so on.

What I get now is index out of range for obvious reasons. And `m` part is also incorrect, cause it does not change.

Comment: ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I explained it, I want those list comprehensions to use characters in each list item, like e, t, and o, then next triplet and so on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You know you can loop though a `string` right? `for c in 'eti'` makes c hold 'e', then 't', then 'i'. Guess that would end your problem with indexing

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is hard to understand I want those 3 list comprehensions instead of m and n use those items from the list each by character

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I know, but not sure how to implement that either. I updated op, I hope it's now more clear.

Comment: What is `mCommon`? What is `newC`? Why do you make it so hard for us? And `com[e]` makes no sense, do you mean `com[0]`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann those two variables have absolutely no significance with my question. com[e] is obviosly incorrect, was done only to illustrate what I want.

Comment: They might seem irrelevant TO YOU, because you know what they are and you know what you're doing, but WE DON'T, and it would very much help everybody to understand your question. The [MCVE guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) doesn't exist for no good reason.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you probably correct. It somehow looks very understandable question to me: how to put those items from the list into list comprehension and cycle through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function that does:

```
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 'e') for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 't') for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 'o') for w in newC]
```

in the first call and:

```
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 'e') for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 't') for w in newC]
newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], 'i') for w in newC]
```

in the second call you could write:

```
com = ['eto', 'eti', 'etn', 'ets', 'eot', 'eoi', 'eon', 'eos', 'eit', 'eio', 'ein']
g_com_index = 0

def adapt_c(newC):
    global g_com_index
    for c in com[g_com_index % len(com)]
        newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], c) for w in newC]
    g_com_index += 1

    return newC
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write the three list comprehension. Loop through the `list`, and then loop through each character to use each of them in as a `replace` argument.

```
for element in list: #element in be 'eto', then 'eti' ...
    for character in element: # character will be 'e','t','i' then 'e','t','o'...
        newC = [w.replace(mCommon[0], character) for w in newC]
```

It is important to notice that the code above assumes `newC` already exists somewhere in your code.